# C++ Excess elements in scalar initializer

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have this assignment that i have to return 2 indices of the numbers in nums that add up to the int target the output is supposed to look like this: [1,2].

But in the return statement i get the error what am i doing wrong?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;i<nums.size();i++){
                if(nums[i] +nums[j]==target){
                    return new int [2]={i,j};
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `new int [2]` is not `vector<int>`. Just do `return {i,j}` and the compiler does all the best.

Answer (score 2):

You choose to use `vector<int>` as return value, so you won't need to use `new`.

Remove extra things.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;i<nums.size();i++){
                if(nums[i] +nums[j]==target){
                    return {i,j};
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you!, i did as you said, it was still missing a return statement later but i managed to do it :)